# Why jar file inside <JAVA_HOME>/jre/lib directory not loaded by bootstrap class loader

Tags: java, classloader

It is being said that

> The bootstrap class loader loads the core Java libraries located in the `<JAVA_HOME>`/jre/lib directory.

And

> The extensions class loader loads the code in the extensions directories `<JAVA_HOME>`/jre/lib/ext,or any other directory specified by the java.ext.dirs system property). It is implemented by the sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader class.

Now if my main program is

```
public class TestSt {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println(String.class.getClassLoader());
        System.out.println(Student.class.getClassLoader());
        System.out.println(TestSt.class.getClassLoader());
    }

}
```

The output is

> null
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@73d16e93
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@73d16e93

Which is fine.

Now if I put Student Jar file in /jre/lib/ext The output is

> null
>   sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader@3d4eac69
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@2a139a55

Which is also fine.

**But I couldnot understand that if I place student jar file in

/jre/lib  directory . Why the output is giving as**

> null
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@73d16e93
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@73d16e93

I was thinking that Student Class in  this case should be loaded from bootstrap class loader, Why it is loaded by application class loader. I think I am missing something. Please let me know where I am wrong.

Comment: Are you asking why the ExtClassLoader is used to load classes in the `ext` directory?

Comment: No, I am asking why bootstrap class loader does not load classes placed inside jre/lib/ directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is only a few directories where all the JARs are loaded automatically.  In directories such as `/jre/lib` only the JARs it expects to load are loaded.  Any other JAR needs to loaded via the classpath.

Comment: So , is it something like bootstarp class loader loads only the class which is provided by JVM internally such as the classes inside rt.jar